# Alternatives to Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an ORM framework for Cocoa, or a framework that accomplishes a similar goal using a different technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745860/is-there-an-orm-framework-for-cocoa-or-a-framework-that-accomplishes-a-similar)

Are there any framework which is in active development which provides ORM functionality? I just hate the fact that the data models in Core Data must be attached to be used. I want to use the as plain objects, and when I want to save etc. I tell the persistence framework to do so. Much like JPA implementations does in Java.

Comment: Writing a custom `init` on your managed object subclasses so that they create themselves relative to the store presumably won't do it? You want explicitly to decide in the future whether objects go into the store, not at the time of creation?

Comment: @Tommy If you read about subclasses of NSManagedObject you will see that it is not an option.

Comment: @Andy: on what grounds are you alleging that's not an option? You'd write your custom `init` to release `self` then to do the usual `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:...`. Possibly the only issue would be obtaining the context, but you could store that as thread or queue context given that they're thread/queue bound anyway. Or, better, supply a factory method that doesn't return the phoney object in the first place. Though the interactions are still fundamentally different from what I think you're asking for — the object is still attached to the store, you've just made the code neater.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)